# how to do conditional background rendering in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want the background to change based on the weather description. However, I am not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions are appreciated! I have bolded the block of code I am referencing.

I was thing I could do something like this -

```
const cloudybg = {
  "clouds" :{
     main: "clouds",
     background: "./assets/cloudy.webp"
  }
}
```

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [data,setData] = useState({})
  const [city,setCity] = useState('')

  // const [state, setState] = useState("")

  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=f92031dc1ecb4ed439d828dad7d31586`

  const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  

  let day = days[d.getDay()];
  let date = d.getDate();
  let month = months[d.getMonth()];
  let year = d.getFullYear();


  return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
  }

  const searchLocation = (event)=> {
    if(event.key === "Enter"){
    axios.get(url).then((response)=>{
      setData(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    setCity("")
    // setState("")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className='search'>
        <input value={city} onChange={event => setCity(event.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={searchLocation}
        placeholder="Enter Location"
        type="text"/>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='top'>
          <div className='location'>
            <p>{data.name}</p>
          </div>
          <div className='temp'>
            {data.main ? <h1>{data.main.temp}°F</h1> : null}
          <div className='date'>{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
            {/* <h1>{data.main.temp}°F</h1> */}
          </div>
          **<div className='description'>
            {data.weather ? <p>{data.weather[0].main}</p>: null}
          </div>**
        </div>

        {data.name != undefined &&
          <div className='bottom'>
            <div className='feels'>
              {data.main ? <p className='bold'>{data.main.feels_like}°F</p>: null}
              <p>Feels Like</p>
            </div>
            <div className='humidity'>
              {data.main ? <p className='bold'>{data.main.humidity}%</p>: null}
              <p>Humidity</p>
            </div>
            <div className='wind'>
              {data.wind ? <p className='bold'>{data.wind.speed} MPH</p>: null}
              <p>Wind Speed</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say axios gives us this answer.

```
let response = {"coord":{"lon":2.3488,"lat":48.8534},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":63,"feels_like":61.02,"temp_min":61.11,"temp_max":65.25,"pressure":1020,"humidity":43},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":11.5,"deg":30},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1651419593,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2041230,"country":"FR","sunrise":1651379422,"sunset":1651431893},"timezone":7200,"id":2988507,"name":"Paris","cod":200}
```

... And the data we want to get from here is

`response.weather[0].main` : `'Clear'`

What I would do is create a hashmap that includes all possibilities (Clear, Clouds, Rain ...) and link to them your colors or paths.

```
const weather_bg_colors = {
    'Clear': '#03e8fc',
    'Clouds': '#ebf2f2',
    'Rain': '#2f6ead'
}
```

I chose to use for this example just random hex colors.
And now you can just get what you want easily by doing ...

`weather_bg_colors["Clear"]` and you get `'#03e8fc'` as answer.

Now you just need to check when the weather changes, get the data, pass it through your hash and modify the BG color accordingly.

Hope this simple solution helps. I don't know if your question has something do to with react.

Comment: Yes, my question has something to do with react. Sorry, I wasn't clear. This is my first time posting a question

Comment: I see. Sorry in this case !

Comment: Could you further clarify anyway? This could be useful in the future. Thank you!

Comment: How. It's simply simulating a file-local database via a Hashmap. You compare the value you got to what you're expecting in the Hashmap and retrieve a color or a path. From there you change your css.